# window return value when closing modal with the X button

Tags: javascript, html, internet-explorer

I am developing a web application that our client calls with something like:

```
var result = window.showModalDialog('http://example.com/myapp','My webapp', 'dialogtop=0;dialogleft=0;dialogwidth:' + (window.screen.width - 200) + ';dialogheight:' + (window.screen.height - 200) + ';status=no;resizable=yes;scroll=yes;maximize:yes;minimize:no;' );
```

and when they close this modal dialog, they capture what we have returned.

We load our response in window.returnValue so they have it in the "result" variable, but if they close our window with the X button, they never get our response, although we have set it. If they close our window by clicking on our "Accept" button, they get the response.

If I try to capture the unload event, and I set window.returnValue again, they don't get it either.

Why is this happening and how can I make sure they get the return value even they press the X?

I can't change how they call our web application, which I know it sucks because it's a dumb way to do things...

They use Internet Explorer exclusively and they run it in mode IE 5...

Comment: Can you share the contents of the `showModalDialog` function?

Comment: showModalDialog is not a function I have developed: https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/API/Window/showModalDialog

Comment: It's because close modal is asynchronous you need to use promises and callback function to execute event when modal is closed. With exact code you can only use default alert/confirm/prompt functions that stop executing of JavaScript, every other function will not block the execution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If possible for you then you can try to make a test with the [onbeforeunload event](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/beforeunload_event)

In that way, you can try to show the prompt to the users and inform them that if they continue with this approach them they can lose the changes they have made on this page. Then you can guide the user with correct steps.

Example:

```
window.onbeforeunload = confirmExit;
function confirmExit()
{
    return "You have attempted to leave this page.  If you have made any changes to the fields without clicking the Accept button, your changes will be lost.  Are you sure you want to exit this page?";
}
```